# How to dynamically create controls in a dynamically created form window in console application

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Using VB.NET 2010 is there any way to dynamically create controls in a dynamically created form window in a console application, Without using any extra ad-on? If so, Can you do event handler(s) for those controls?

Comment: No, you don't use forms and controls in console application. Although, technically, you can create your objects in memory but then, what use of it?

Comment: I am using this in my programming language to pre add controls then show the window. It will make more sense when I release it to the public in a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a Form displaying you already have a reference to System.Windows.Forms.  You add controls to your form in a similar fashion as you would have for your Form.  To wire up Events you use the [AddHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) Statement:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module Module1

    Private m_frmTest As Form = Nothing

    Sub Main()

        Dim frmTest As New Form()

        Dim btnTest As New Button()
        btnTest.Text = "Test"
        btnTest.Top = 100
        btnTest.Left = 100

        AddHandler btnTest.Click, AddressOf SimpleButtonClickHandler

        frmTest.Controls.Add(btnTest)

        frmTest.ShowDialog()            

    End Sub

    Private Sub SimpleButtonClickHandler()

        MsgBox("Test")

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You have helped me much more then you think, I had to get my program published to the internet within 2 days. I needed to know a way to do this without using .NET Framework 4.6. Thanks! What I did was since you cant add different commands for different controls, I just went and made it so you code it in a external file for the control in which the event handler detects. In smaller words, You can code events for different controls using this method.